# C - Invalid use of sizeof for incomplete type (struct input_dev)

Tags: c, linux, input

I am writing a program which interacts with linux input subsystem. Following is my main file I am trying to compile:

```
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void idevcreate() {
  struct input_dev idev;
  memset(&idev, 0, sizeof(struct input_dev));
}
```

When I try to compile this I get following error:

```
Invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type (struct input_dev)
```

I guess the program is not able to find definition of `input_dev`. Is there anything I am missing over here?

Comment: Where is `struct input_dev` defined?

Comment: I don't know if it's an answer really, but instead of explicitly calling memset, you can just do `struct input_dev idev = {};` and get the same effect with a lot less typing.

Comment: @DanielFischer: as far as I can tell it should be in <linux/input.h>, but the OP should check the specific machine being used.

Comment: @JohnZwinck It's not mentioned in mine, that's why I asked.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: i checked my input.h and didn't find input_dev defined there. Will implement the change you have suggested and see if it works.

Comment: @DanielFischer: interesting--it's in 2.6.x here: http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/include/linux/input.h ...but apparently not for everybody.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Perhaps it was removed in 3.x?

Comment: You are mixing kernel-level and user-level headers. This is not going to work. Are you writing a driver or a user-space program?

Comment: @n.m.: I am writing a user space program.

Comment: Then headers in `linux/` are not for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to simply locate your system's definition of `struct input_dev` and #include the relevant header.  I'd do something like this:

```
grep -r "struct input_dev" /usr/include
```

Comment: Turned up nothing. I guess it was indeed removed.